# Habilitar htaccess apache 2.2.15 en Scientific Linux

Tags: linux, apache, servidor

Hola chicos buenas tardes,

Resumidamente mi problema es el siguiente >

Necesito habilitar el fichero htaccess, la web actualmente esta funcionado con el servicio de apache 2.2.15 y el S.O que la contiene es Scientific Linux.

He estado leyendo los tutos en la red los únicos pasos que realice fueron lo siguientes :
Activar el modrewrite y el AllowOverride

Pero francamente de ahí me da pavor meter la pata, por eso recurro a su ayuda.

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para habilitar los archivos .htaccess necesitas en el contexto `Directory` habilitar las siguientes directivas:

```
AllowOverride All
```

AllowOverride hace que el archivo .htaccess (creado por el usuario) sea tomado como parte de la configuración (creada por el admin), en el directorio y los sub-directorios del contexto que estás modificando. También, AllowOverride permite afinar el permiso para no habilitar todo el espectro de posibilidades.

Aquí tienes el manual de Apache
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html

Adicionalmente, si tu .htaccess va a ser utilizado para escribir URL bonitas (como hace p.ej. Wordpress) necesitas habilitar el soporte de rewrite con:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

y la opción de `FollowSymLinks` habilitada en el contexto `Directory`:

```
Option FollowSymLinks
```

que puede o no, estar junto a otras opciones como `Indexes`, pero eso ya es otro tema.

Comment: Oye ! muchas gracias ! Aplique tu guía y leí la documentación compartida, con mucha calma. Muchas gracias !